# How can I install this firefox extension from github?

Tags: github, firefox

how can I install this extension on github into firefox? I dl'ed the files, put them in a zip but ff says "broken".
https://gitlab.com/alanramsey/auto-reload-tab

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to look for it in https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/ and install it from there.

If you just want to test it as part if some development work, you will need to

```
download the files,
.zip them,
rename the .zip to .xpi
Use the "This Firefox" in these instructions to load the add-on temporarily: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/about:debugging
```